# How to resolve dependencies for custom Nutch plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, ivy, nutch

I am struggling with Ivy and dependency resolution in Eclipse. I have created a custom plug-in for Nutch, which has dependencies on another project in my Eclipse workspace. Now when I build it it complains about the classes from that project. I presume the standard Eclipse mechanism in build classpath settings (where I've added that project as dependency project) doesn't work, so I have to define dependency via ivy.xml. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Old way is to :
declare the dependencies inside the `NUTCH_INSTALLATION/src/plugin/<your_plugin>/plugin.xml` file.

If you want to use ivy : declare the dependencies inside `<dependencies>` tag in the `NUTCH_INSTALLATION/src/plugin/<your_plugin>/ivy.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Basically the problem is that plugin.xml only allows dependencies on other plugins. The project is not a plugin project, just Java project. Secondly, I am indeed trying to use ivy, and I read tutorials on how to declare dependencies on repository, but I can't find an example how to declare a dependency on another local project. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: i think u need to create a jar out of the local java project and then add that jar to the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the related [page of Nutch wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/HowToMakeCustomSearch).